# Unity serialize all components in a game object anonymously

Tags: unity-game-engine, serialization, deserialization

I'm working on a free to play multi-player game, and I'm trying to bake my own networking system.

Currently I have something like this

```
public class NetworkedEntity : Monobehavior

public Guid guid;

awake()
{
    /* serialize all components in game object, 
    *  broadcast to the server to then be instantiated on all
    *  players machines
    */
}

public void SendSync(object obj) {
    /* Send some JSON over TCP */
}

public void SendAsync(object obj) {
   /* Send some JSON over UDP */
}
```

I have a secondary class that is a singleton for my TCP/UDP connections.
Now the question I have here is, can I use Newtonsoft or the JsonUtility to send a component (list) JSON and instantiate it(them)?

Some psuedo code about how I want to handle awake it

```
   new NetworkContainer { Guid = this.guid, Components = GetAllComponents() }
   // send over TCP
```

Now this is fine, and makes total sense to me but when I receive this, how do I know what type to serialize anonymously? I was thinking using reflection and creating a dictionary of the TypeName, and sending that in the JSON as well.

I know I can be more specific and only serialize one component at a time on its awake, but I wanted to make an extensible networking API that required less annotation with attributes, and to extract things away to one network class/api

Edit: I thought I'd add I have a Set of all the Gameobjects that exist with their network guid. If it exists we either add or update the component, otherwise instantiate the gameobject and add every component received

Comment: Could you provide an example scenario? It feels pretty broad for interpretation to me. Are you refering to the actual Unity Component classes? Do mean dynamically building a gameobject component structure?

Comment: Yes, I could write an example if you'd like

Comment: I wanted to clarify (I read your comment on the go) I want to dynamically instantiate and add monobehaviors to Gameobjects not use the component class

Comment: Sure. Use your own json syntax rather than JsonUtility.